# Getting rid of a floating point with Tikz and evaluate

Tags: tikz-pgf, floating-point

Salutations wonderful people,

I think you will understand my tragic problem with a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->,>=latex] (-.5,0) -- (5.5,0);
  \draw [->,>=latex] (0,-.5) -- (0,5.5);

  \foreach \x in {0,1,2,...,5}
  {
    \foreach \y [evaluate = \y as \s using {(\x+\y)*(\x+\y+1)/2+\y}] in {0,1,...,5}
    {
      \draw (\x,\y)  node{$\s$};
    } ;
  } ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following :

[image]

The most acute among you may have recognized an illustration of the Cantor polynomial.

As you see, the results of the "evaluate" are displayed with a floating point, and I would be extremely joyful and infinitely grateful if any of you could tell me how to have it gone.

Thank to all of you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour of `\pgfmathprintnumber` gives integer results

```
\draw (\x,\y)  node{$\pgfmathprintnumber{\s}$};
```

[image]

#### Notes:

- I replaced `\input` with `\usepackage{}` which is the usual way of importing a package with LaTeX.
- I elimianted extra `;` as those result in

  ```
  Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
  ```

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->,>=latex] (-.5,0) -- (5.5,0);
  \draw [->,>=latex] (0,-.5) -- (0,5.5);

  \foreach \x in {0,1,2,...,5}
  {
    \foreach \y [evaluate = \y as \s using {(\x+\y)*(\x+\y+1)/2+\y}] in {0,1,...,5}
    {
      \draw (\x,\y)  node{$\pgfmathprintnumber{\s}$};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, it was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!